# Phonegap, IOS , Device doesn't receive notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, phonegap

I am developing a Phonegap application for iOS and would like to enable push notifications. I use GCM and when I send notification google return me success but IOS device doesn't show anything .

There is my code:

```
"android": {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxx", "icon": "icon", "badge": "true", "iconColor": "white", "sound": "true", "soundname": "nb"
        },

        "ios": {

          "senderID": "xxxxxxxx",

          "alert": "true",
          "badge": "true",
          "sound": "true",
          "usesGCM":true,
          "sandbox":false,

          },

        "windows": {}
```

.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to be complete

Answer (score 0):

First of all install the plugin of push notification.

```
phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

After the write the java script code as below for iOS push

```
var note = new apn.Notification();
            note.badge = 1;
            note.sound = "beep.wav"; //path to your sound
            note.contentAvailable = 1;
            note.alert = { "body" : msg, "action-loc-key" : "Show Me!" , "launch-image" : "mysplash.png"};
            //note.payload = {'uuid': data.uuid}; // additional payload 
            note.device = data.deviceId;

            var callback = function(errorNum, notification){
                console.log('Error is: %s', errorNum);
                //console.log("Note " + JSON.stringify(notification));
            }
            var options = {
                gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
                errorCallback: callback,
                cert: 'test.pem', 
                key:  'test.pem',  // ** NEED TO SET TO YOURS
                passphrase: '', // ** NEED TO SET TO YOURS
                //port: 2195,                       
                enhanced: true,                   
                cacheLength: 100                  
            }

            var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);    

            apnProvider.send(note, myDevice).then( (result) => {        
                console.log("Result :: ",JSON.stringify(result));
            });
```

It will works.

Comment: I use gcm for IOS notification gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com' is right for gcm ?

Comment: GCM means Google Cloud Messaging which is only use for Android.

Comment: No, Google Cloud Messaging is for IOS too.

Comment: Yes, and its called FCM (Firebase Cloud  messaging). But according to your sample my example is better.